# Recommendations about a book or tutorial to learn about labview

Tags: labview

I would like to find the best tuttorial or free pdf book. To learn Labview, I am new to this program. If I were in Spanish, it would be better if there was no problem.

Answer (score 3):

I am working with Richard Jennings on the fifth edition of the book "LabVIEW Graphical Programming". It is scheduled to release later on this year.

In the meantime, check out the LabVIEW Wiki at https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/Home

You can ask questions and find examples at the LAVA and NI forums at
https://lavag.org/
https://forums.ni.com/t5/Discussion-Forums/ct-p/discussion-forums

You could also look for a LabVIEW User Group in a Spanish speaking community. They might have more information in Spanish. Check out:
https://forums.ni.com/t5/User-Groups/ct-p/user-groups

Answer (score 2):

It's an old one but a good one:

[LabVIEW for Everyone: Graphical Programming Made Easy and Fun](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1207034)

It brings you from zero to hero with most of the key concepts along the way to become a Certified LabVIEW Developer.  Note, newer architectures are not included but it is perfect for a beginner.

You can read it for free from Reilly for 10 days: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/labview-for-everyone/0131856723/